# Nginx not serve static assets in rails 4 assets pipeline

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, nginx, server

recent days I was trying deploy my application to production. I have deployed finish but my app not showing icon.

this config in app/config/environments/production.rb

```
config.cache_classes = true
config.eager_load = true
config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
config.action_controller.perform_caching = false
config.serve_static_assets = true
config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
config.assets.compile = false
config.assets.digest = true
config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect'
```

and in nginx.conf

```
location ~ ^/(assets)/  {
 root /my_public_path_here;
 gzip_static on;
 expires max;
 add_header Cache-Control public;
}
```

Please leave message if you have problem similar, thanks so munch!

Comment: do you have public/assets/all.js.gz and public/assets/all.css.gz in place?

Comment: yes , i have compiled assets, and it available in public/assets.

Comment: turn access/error logs on and put output here.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look on [this](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/lib/support/nginx/gitlab) Nginx configuration example as consistent and full functional. This config discribes *Nginx* proxying of *Rails app* runing on *[Unicorn](http://unicorn.bogomips.org/)* via Unix socket. regarding your question, your `location ~ ^/(assets)/ {...` part seems to be correct.

Try this for `try_files` part (note `$uri $uri/index.html $uri.html`):

```
  location / {
    ## Serve static files from defined root folder.
    ## @your_up_stream_name is a named location for the upstream fallback, see below.
    try_files $uri $uri/index.html $uri.html @your_up_stream_name;
  }
```

Also make sure `@your_up_stream_name` is correct upstream name. Just in case, make sure toy have assest precompilled;-)

```
$ RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

Comment: @Peter can you provide some logs or additional config? That is very interesting issue. I'm trying to understand where the problem is: is Nginx configuration wrong or Rails doesn't work properly. E.g. can you access to assets directly i.e. not via Nginx?

Comment: this is nginx log
```e/36.0.1985.143 Safari/537.36"
118.69.34.46 - - [20/Nov/2014:17:52:14 +0900] "GET /assets/add.png HTTP/1.1" 404 198 "<my-url>" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.143 Safari/537.36"
118.69.34.46 - - [20/Nov/2014:17:52:14 +0900] "GET /assets/export.png HTTP/1.1" 404 198 "<my-url>" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.143 Safari/537.36"```

Answer (score 0):

I use something like this to serve static assets if they exist

```
location / {
  try_files $uri @app;
}

location @app {
  # rails app stuff here...
}
```

Perhaps you're just missing a [`try_files`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) directive like above.

Comment: thank you for reply. I have already add try_files $uri @myapp; but it's not working.

Comment: try_files helps with complex logic, but root is enough most of time. Once no location meets request, root is used to serve file from disk